# How to assign date value for schema type Date in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Trying to set date like dd/mm/yyyy format for date type schema in mongoose but not working.How to set it?
Here my code.

```
Getting errer like string is not supporting Date type.
```

model.js:

```
let customModel = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    today: Date,
    afterfivedays: Date
});
```

data.controller.js:

```
const data = [ 
{ 
    firstName: :"S",
    lastName: "Michel",
    today: "01/06/2020",
    afterfivedays: "06/06/2020",
} 
]
```

Comment: As the error says you are trying to store a String in a Date field. You could use the js Date constructor to create the required date and format it on the visualization instead

Comment: @IvanBertola: How to do ot?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it will cast the value to native js date

[image]

So you can pass

```
const data = [ 
{ 
    firstName: :"S",
    lastName: "Michel",
    today: "2020-06-01",
    afterfivedays: "2020-06-06"
} 
]
```

Comment: var dateString = "10/23/2015"; 

then convert to  new Date(dateString) => Fri Oct 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose recognizes default JS format to parse it.
so convert date into default JS date format.
Or more info about working with dates visit [Mongoose Date pattern](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html)

```
const data = [ 
  { 
   firstName: :"S",
   lastName: "Michel",
   today: "2020-06-01",
   afterfivedays: "2020-06-06",
}
```

]